# What is the iterator_to_array function in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm having a hard time understanding PHP's `iterator_to_array` function.

I tried reading the manual but that didn't help.

What is it? How can I use it? What are the appropriate use cases?

Comment: read  more : http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php

Comment: thanks for comment ..i did not get fully via manual so that i asked here?

Comment: When you have iterator (object which implements interface Iterator http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) you could by function "iterator_to_array" get array of elements which return method "current" and if you use parameter "$use_keys" then result of method key will be used as key for returned array.

Comment: you need to look what iterator is, after you understand how iterator work then you dont need to ask this question

Comment: My understanding is iterator_to_array function returns array despite of what is passed into ( object or another array). returned array can be associative or indexed depending on second argument(true or false).

Comment: @NarayanBhandari you cannot pass an array to ```iterator_to_array()```. It requires you to pass something that implements *Traversable*. And an *array*, not being an *object*, doesn't implement it.

Answer (score 11):

In a nutshell, `iterator_to_array()` function takes an iterator of type [`Traversable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) and convert it to an associative/non-associative array, depending upon the argument provided. From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php),

```
array iterator_to_array ( Traversable $iterator [, bool $use_keys = true ] )
```

The function takes the following two arguments,

- The first argument is of type `Traversal`, which is an interface. Both [`IteratorAggregate`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php) and [`Iterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) class extends this interface. You can implement these two classes in your custom class, like this:

  ```
  class myIterator implements IteratorAggregate {
      private $array = array('key1'=>'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4');

      public function getIterator(){
          return new ArrayIterator($this->array);
      }
  }

  $obj = new myIterator;
  $array = iterator_to_array($obj->getIterator(), true);
  var_dump($array);
  ```

  Or,

  ```
  class myIterator implements Iterator {
      private $key;
      private $array = array('key1'=>'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4');

      public function __construct(){
          $this->key = key($this->array);
      }

      public function rewind(){
          reset($this->array);
          $this->key = key($this->array);
      }

      public function current(){
          return $this->array[$this->key];
      }

      public function key(){
          return $this->key;
      }

      public function next(){
          next($this->array);
          $this->key = key($this->array);
      }

      public function valid(){
          return isset($this->array[$this->key]);
      }
  }

  $obj = new myIterator;
  $array = iterator_to_array($obj, true);
  var_dump($array);
  ```

  **The most important point** to note here is that argument 1 passed to `iterator_to_array()` function must implement interface `Traversable`, so you cannot directly pass an array or object of any other type to this function. See the following example,

  ```
  $array = array('key1'=>'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4');
  $array = iterator_to_array($array, true);  // wrong
  ```
- The second argument is a boolean value, to indicate whether to use the iterator element keys as index or not. See [Example #1 here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php#refsect1-function.iterator-to-array-examples).

Answer (score 4):

Iterators are useful because they allow you to use a custom defined order of data within a `foreach` loop. Let's take this (slightly pared down) example from [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php#iterator.examples):

```
class myIterator implements Iterator {
    private $position = 0;
    private $array = array(
        "firstelement",
        "secondelement",
        "lastelement",
    );

    public function __construct() {
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    function rewind() {
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    function current() {
        return $this->array[$this->position];
    }

    function key() {
        return $this->position;
    }

    function next() {
        ++$this->position;
    }

    function valid() {
        return isset($this->array[$this->position]);
    }
}

$it = new myIterator;
```

To iterate over it, we can use a `foreach` loop just like an array:

```
foreach($it as $ele){
    echo $ele;
}
```

*Unlike* an array, however, you cannot access a single element without iterating to it first. Attempting to do so will give you a fatal error:

```
/*
 * Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type myIterator as array
 * in /home/hpierce/sandbox.php
 */
echo $it[1];

//Iterating to the second element.
$it->next();

// "secondelement"
echo $it->current();
```

To access a single element, you could use `iterator_to_array()` to cast the iterator as an array and then access the element without the extra step:

```
$array = iterator_to_array($it);

// "secondelement"
echo $array[1];
```

If you know ahead of time that you will need to access a single element within an iterator, you should consider using [ArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) instead.

Comment: Uncovered this one, it's kind of a gem of an explanation when dealing with Iterators and the differences in how they work compared to arrays.  Helpful even in Symfony 5.0, thank you for the clarity so many years later, @HPierce!  :-)